# Unordered list inside (nested in) another unordered list with <li> in Angular

Tags: angular

Here are the lists:

```
List1 = [{name:A}, {name:B}, {name:C}, {name:D}, {name:F}]
List2 = [{name:e}, {name:g}, {name:t}]
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let list of list1">{{list1.name}}        
        <ul *ngIf="list.name === 'C'">
            <li *ngFor="let list_2 of list2" >{{ list_2.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want this result:

```
A
B
C
   *e
   *g
   *t
D
F
```

But there are mistake(s) that I can't find. Please give me a hand finding them, or show me a new implementation.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the actual result? What errors display in the console?

Comment: What is `list1`? What is `list`? What has a name? Do you realize that TypeScript is case-sensitive?

Comment: any type. Yes I realize that TypeScript is case-sensitive. Mistake is that nested list is not display as inner/child element.

Answer (score 0):

In app.component.ts, make public so that can be used outside of .ts file. Name is should be the string

```
 public list1 = [{ name: 'A' }, { name: 'B' }, { name: 'C' }, { name: 'D' }, { name: 'F' }]
 public list2 = [{ name: 'e' }, { name: 'g' }, { name: 't' }]
```

In app.component.html

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let list of list1">
      {{list.name}}
      <ul *ngIf="list.name=='C'">
        <li *ngFor="let list_2 of list2">{{ list_2.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with HTML because TypeScript is case-sensitive.
So you should type with the correct case.

Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let list of List1">{{list.name}}        
        <ul *ngIf="list.name === 'C'">
            <li *ngFor="let list_2 of List2" >{{ list_2.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```